# Is it possible to query channels in GetStream by channel IDs list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getstream-io

I need to query channels by providing list if IDs although i can't find any documentation on it.
I tried to query channels without any filters like this : `chatClient.queryChannels();` it gives me only 10 channeles.
I tried query channel by members

```
const filter = { members: { $in: ['thierry'] } }; 
const sort = { };
chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort);
```

It's still provides me only 10 channels.
Is it possible in getstream to get channels by it's IDs or CIDs ?

I need something like this :

```
const filter = { ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'...] }; 
const sort = { };
const channels = await chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to filter with `id` or `cid`. You can add the same in the filter.

```
const filter = { id: { $in: ['ID1', 'ID2'] } };
const sort = { };
chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort);
```

It's given in the [documentation of query channels](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/query_channels/) as well, but couldn't find an example here. Hope the above example helped.